# Concurrent matplotlib.pyplot Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

When I run this code the second matplotlib.pyplot window only appears after I have closed the first one when I open them sequentially like this. How do I display multiple windows concurrently?

```
 def graph(xList, yList, string):
     xArr = numpy.array(xList)
     yArr = numpy.array(yList)
     matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xArr,yArr)
     matplotlib.pyplot.title(string)
     matplotlib.pyplot.show()



graph(posX,posY, "positive")
graph(negX,negY, "negative")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell pyplot to show the figures only once everything is done.
So create as many figures as you wish, but only call `show()` at the end

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
posX = numpy.arange(19)
posY = posX
negX,negY = posX*(-1), posY*(-1)


def graph(xList, yList, string):
    xArr = numpy.array(xList)
    yArr = numpy.array(yList)
    matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xArr,yArr)
    matplotlib.pyplot.title(string)

graph(posX,posY, "positive")
graph(negX,negY, "negative") 

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include `show()` in your plotting functions, let the calling code decide when to display the plots.

Most plotting functions will reuse the current figure if there is one. If you want a new figure you have to explicitly create it.

The following code will display two figures at once. Notice how a new figure is created before the second plot and `show()` is only called after all the plotting has been done.

```
x = numpy.arange(10)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, x)
matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, x**2)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```